# Mongoose query doesn't work with the filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

I'm testing a nodejs snippet to do iteration with my example mongodb collection `users`. But the query never worked. The full users collection are printed.
The standalone mongodb is setup in EKS cluster.
Why the query `{name: "Baker one"}` didn't work?

- The code is:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const url = "mongodb://xxxxxx:27017/demo";


main().catch(error => console.error(error.stack));
async function main() {

// Connect to DB
const db = await mongoose.connect(url);
console.log("Database connected!");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

// Init Model
const Users = mongoose.model("Users", {}, "users");
const users = await Users.find({name: "Baker one"}).exec();
// Iterate
for await (const doc of users) {
  console.log(doc);
  console.log("users...");
}

console.log("about to close...");
db.disconnect();

}
```

- The users collection:
  [image]
- The execution result:

```
$ node modify.js
Database connected!
{ _id: new ObjectId("610f512c52fa99dcd04aa743"), name: 'Baker one' }
users...
{ _id: new ObjectId("61193ed9b8af50d530576af6"), name: 'Bill S' }
users...
about to close...
```

Comment: `mongoose.model("Users", {}, "users")` would be defining a schema with no fields.  Does it behave differently if the Users model actually contains a `name` field?

Answer (score 1):

This line could be the culprit (note that the schema has been defined with no fields like Joe pointed out in the comments).

```
const Users = mongoose.model("Users", {}, "users");
```

In this case, I had to add StrictQuery option in the Schema constructor to make it work, like so:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({}, { collection: "Users", strictQuery : false });
```